# return value Vs reference (in assembly)

Tags: c++, assembly, reference, x86-64, return-value

After taking a look at a few questions (and answers) regarding this topic, I tried the below simple code in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9z7MbqaxW).

```
#include <iostream>


class TwoInts
{
public:
    TwoInts( ) = default;

    const int& getAByRef( ) const;

    int getAByVal( ) const;

private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

const int& TwoInts::getAByRef( ) const
{
    return a;
}

int TwoInts::getAByVal( ) const
{
    return a;
}


int main( )
{
    TwoInts ti;

    const int& num1 { ti.getAByRef( ) };
    const int num2 { ti.getAByVal( ) };

    //std::cout << num1 << ' ' << num2 << '\n';
}
```

Now I see different codes generated for the two member functions `getAByRef` and `getAByVal`:

```
TwoInts::getAByRef() const:
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
TwoInts::getAByVal() const:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
```

Can someone explain what those two different assembly instructions are doing?

Comment: I don't understand what the question has to do with C++ (it appears to be simply "what do these assembly opcodes mean?", and they *would mean the same thing no matter whether you got the assembly source by compiling a C++ program or writing it by hand*). I also don't understand what kind of answer you're asking for - we can't "explain" things in a vacuum, because there is no way for us to know why you don't already understand. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and considering looking up an ASM tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each member function gets `this` pointer as an implicit first function argument, as dictated by [Itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) (not to be confused with Itanium architecture) used by GCC. `this` is passed in the `rdi` register and a value is returned (if it's trivial, and here it is) in the `rax` (`eax`) register according to x86-64 System V ABI (see comments by Peter Cordes below).

In the first case, when you return `a` by reference, you're actually returning an address of `a`. `a` is the first member, so its address is the same as that of the object, i.e. `this`. Hence, you just set `rax` to `rdi`.

In the second case, when you return `a` by value, you need to do actual dereferencing. That's what `DWORD PTR [rdi]` is doing. `DWORD PTR` means that you want to fetch 4 bytes (`sizeof(int)`).

If you put some data member before `a`, you'll see an additional offset added to `rdi`.

Comment: Wow, this makes it more clear. Now my other question is that what is the purpose of `DWORD PTR` there? I mean does it refer to `rdi`? Isn't `rdi` a *quadword* register?

Comment: Oh! so for example if we wanted to fetch an `int64_t` from `rdi` then we would use `QWORD PTR` or something like that? Sorry if I'm asking weird questions.

Comment: Otherwise a good explanation, however, what you describe (and what OP's assembly shows) is a typical Unix **x86-64** calling convention (System V **AMD64 ABI**).
Not to be confused with (now discontinued) **Itanium**, which has a totally different microarchitecture (**IA-64**).

Comment: @heapunderrun Itanium ABI should not be confused with Itanium architecture. GCC (and Clang) use Itanium ABI on other platforms, too.

Comment: The C arg->register mapping is from the AMD64 psABI to the System V ABI, aka x86-64 SysV, as @heapunderrun says.  The "Itanium **C++ ABI**" is how we define C++ semantics on top of a C calling convention, and is called "Itanium" for lack of a better name, because it was first developed for that ISA.  (And unlike a C ABI, it does *not* have anything to do with register names).  The C++ ABI says which objects can't be passed in registers even if they're small enough for the C ABI to do that.  e.g. based on triviality of construct / destructor.  Also how try/catch compile, and virtual funcs, etc.

Comment: TL:DR: this answer should really be talking about the x86-64 System V ABI as the reason why the first arg goes in RDI.  The Itanium C++ ABI is why the first arg is an implicit `this` pointer, although passing it that way is essentially universal across calling conventions, except ones like x86 Windows `thiscall` where there's one arg-passing register for `this`, never for any other arg, because it's *only* used for member functions.  Forgot to say last comment that the reason a C++ ABI would keep an arg out of regs is if the object needs to have an address.